# Selecting from outer apply using case when

Tags: sql

I'm using outer apply to create find two results but I only need to use one depending on what they return. I test the rows using Case in the select. But it doesn't work as intended.

```
select (case when s.ord_hdrnumber = '0' then (case when s2.ord_hdrnumber = NULL then s3.ord_hdrnumber else s2.ord_hdrnumber end) else s.ord_hdrnumber end) ord, 
into #stops2
from #Stops s left join assetassignment a
    on s.lgh_number = a.lgh_number
    outer apply (select top 1 * from #stops where #stops.mov_number = s.mov_number and #stops.stp_sequence > s.stp_sequence and #stops.ord_hdrnumber > 0 order by #stops.stp_sequence asc) s2
    outer apply (select top 1 * from #stops where #stops.mov_number = s.mov_number and #stops.stp_sequence < s.stp_sequence and #stops.ord_hdrnumber > 0 order by #stops.stp_sequence desc) s3
```

So the 'output' column should always have an order number.

Result

```
Output  s.ord   s2.ord  s3.ord
NULL    0       NULL    2979070 
NULL    0       NULL    2979070 
2979070 2979070 NULL    2979070 
2979070 2979070 2979070 NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is SQL Server.. Change ` = NULL` to `IS NULL`.

Comment: Possibly many issues here as the code is not well written, however I know s2.ord_hdrnumber = NULL will not work, you need s2.ord_hdrnumber IS NULL

Comment: Is Null worked ... embarrassing